# Importing subdirectory files into another directory in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I am making a Python program. In my program, I want to import files from sub-directories into another directory. The file hierarchy is as follows:

```
arc_panther/
├── MonteCarlo/
│   ├── main.py
│   
└── Supporting_Files/
    └── moduler
           DataExtraction
              check.py
```

I want to call a function from `check.py` to `main.py`. How do I import the file?

Any help is this topic is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows:

```
from Supporting_Files.modular.DataExtraction import check
```

Instead of `check` import the function or class in the `check.py` file you need.

Comment: i alreay do this .but not able to import it